# Vba code for word bold and deletion

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a variable which contains five words. 
Eg:- My name is Albert Einstein.

If the first word is "My" then it should be bold, else the word has to be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Hope the below code logic could help you to solve the problem:

```
Sub test1()

    Debug.Print boldAndDeletion("Your name is Albert Einstein.")

End Sub

Function boldAndDeletion(inputString As String) As String

    Dim splitStr1 As Variant

    splitStr1 = Split(inputString, " ")

    If splitStr1(0) = "My" Then
        boldAndDeletion = "<b>My</b>" & Mid(inputString, 3)
    Else
        boldAndDeletion = Empty
    End If

End Function
```